# bootstrap z-index issue with dropdown button in header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap in my website, i create a new dropdown button and I added in the header, my problem is when I click on dropdown that menu is appear under the others elements, I will add here an image to see what is the problem [image], I think the problem is z-index:

here is my html code:

```
<div class="page">
        <div class="header-container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="header">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">
                            <div class="dropdown">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a demo of the above or live link?

Comment: Is it behind the lower elements, or is it being hidden by overflow masking on the header?

Comment: I don't know yet i search for two hourrs

Comment: We need to see your full menu markup or a demo. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: unfortunately i can;t create a demo there is a magento website and I can't to add there

Comment: Manoj Kumar I find your email and i send you a email with the subject: Bootrstrap problem

Comment: Check for `overflow: hidden` set for one of yours containers

Comment: Andriy Horen i search nothing related to overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the wrapper. It has a property `overflow: hidden` which hides anything that is outside its area. Remove this and it will work. Not a `z-index` problem.

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden; // Remove
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Overlapping menu]

Comment: is true, perfect Manoj, is work like a charm, thank you so much

Comment: Welcome, Robert! Glad it helped :)

Comment: Hi, any idea how that can be accomplished in bootstrap 4, there is no "wrapper"? I can open a separate question if you like.

Comment: @NoChance Opening a separate question will be better.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve my problem using z-index. It might have been a different issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it This Code in your header

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Dropdowns within Navs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```